# How to enable STARTTLS in a Unix operating system

Tags: sendmail

I am using old `HP-UNIX` server. I want to enable `STARTTLS` which is not there in the server. I went through some blogs all are saying something about certificates and keys but I don't have these configurations in my `sendmail.cf`.

Comment: If you don't have them in your config, that would explain they aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

If your HP-UX is older than 11.11, you probably will have to install 3rd party MTA.   Otherwise, this HP document should help: http://support.hp.com/id-en/document/c00916394

> Note that STARTTLS is a feature/functionality provided with HP's port of sendmail 8.13.3 from the Opensource version.